# Access Google Calendar From Web App Events Without Users Logging In

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a website in which I am hitting the Google Calendar API and successfully pulling the events from a specified calendar. I am just now realizing, however, that I was only able to see the events because I was signed into that Google account while on the webpage using Chrome browser. When I logged out of the account on Chrome I could no longer see the event data. I guess not just anyone is authorized.

Here's the question: **Can any user, without logging in, view my Google Calendar's events on my webpage?**

I know there's something called server accounts but it looks really heavy for what I'm trying to accomplish. I do not need to access any Google user information nor do I need to access any application data. I simply want to display information from my Google Calendar using the Google Calendar API. I don't even need to use the API, honestly. I am successfully pulling data from a public Google Sheets and figured the calendar would work better, but then ran into this problem.

Comment: If you want to use a server sided language you can use a service account.   You can share the calendar in question with the service account and it will be able to read it without any user longin. JavaScript doesn't support service account authentication though.

Comment: So, for instance, upon page load, I could use the JavaScript to call a PHP script that authenticates the website as a whole (an actor posing as a user). From there, I could then call the event data from the Calendar, just as normal. Could you point me to some relevant documentation for this situation?

Comment: Yes you can have a php script feed the access token to JavaScript script. I have seen it done not sure how secure I would call the solution. It works sorry I don't have any code for you.